# Inner static class fields visibility

Tags: java

I have two class like below

```
public class A{

  private static class B{
   private static int s1;
   private static int s2;
   private int x;

  }
}
```

In class B all fields are private and these all fields should not be accessible in class A. But there is a 'Mystery' that static fields are accessible in class A and

```
private int x
```

is not accessible. My question is that why private static fields are accessible in Class A?

Note: My B class is static and its constructor is private.

Comment: Both instance and static fields are accessible.

Comment: In class A they are all accessible. If you want acces x use "new B().x"

Comment: try them withot making instance like B.s1

Comment: How can you access an instance variable without creating an instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to answer given by @Uwe Plonus (+1) I can suppose that you tried to access non-static field `x` via class `B` without creating the instance, i.e.

`B.x = 5;`

You have to create instance of claas `B` to access its instance members, i.e.

`new B().x = 5;`

Comment: My B class is static and its constructor is private. I cant make instance of this class.

Comment: ok got the answer that inner is A class context so we can access all its private members. More, we can access static  by dot(.) and instance can not. So actually all are visible to A. Thanks alot all of you.

Answer (score 7):

Fields and methods in inner classes are always visible from the outer class. This is by design. If you want to hide your fields and methods use a separate class.

Comment: _Java srikes again._ SMH

Answer (score 2):

Even if the inner class members are defined as private and protected, outer class access the members of inner class. These qualifiers(private,protected etc) will only affect the visibility of the inner class in classes that derive from the outer class.Just refer to the members properly :

```
class A{

  private static class B{
   private static int s1;
   private static int s2;
   private int x;

  }

  int y = new A.B().x;

  int z = B.s1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing instance with static, look at the code below the outer class can access all the private fields, the only difference is that if the field is not static you will need an instance of the object.

```
public class Test {

    public void dummy() {

        new B().x = 5;

        new SB().x = 5; //access field by instance

        SB.sx = 5; //access static
    }

    private class B {
        private int x;

    }

    private static class SB {

        private SB() {}

        private static int sx;

        private int x;

    }

}
```

Comment: My B class constructor is private. I cant make instance of this class

Comment: @Talha just added a private constructor for this example and you can see that it works... it wont work if you try to create the instance from another class instead the outer class

Answer (score 2):

[**Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) says

> Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private.
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields.